# Shader showing as black from one scene to another

Tags: unity-game-engine, cg

I have a small question on Unity. I have 2 scenes; one is a 'menu' with a simple button, and the other one is my scene with an object that has a custom terrain shader with it. You can see the code for the custom shader here: 
[Unity shader error, unrecognised identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43954736/unity-shader-error-unrecognised-identifier)
For some reason, I am being presented with this situation where:

1. If Game scene is run in editor -> the shader is loaded
2. If Menu scene is run in editor and then go to Game scene -> the
   shader is loaded
3. If Game scene is run after build -> the shader is loaded
4. If Menu scene is run after build and then go to game scene -> the
   shader is NOT loaded

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Is there something like a script or behavior that loads/assigns the shader in the scene? And are you getting the nasty purple missing shader/material color?

Comment: Show the code you have. Seems like something in the menu scene is responsible for the correct behavior.